# Using Subsonic with Firebird

Tags: subsonic, firebird

I have a dotnet application with a Firebird Database back-end. I am planning to use Subsonic with it v3. Does anybody have any experience with it. Are there any major issue with it ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...written for Firebird and am planning to use Firebird with it.?
I think the case is clear...isn't it?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you talking about using SubSonic with Firebird?

Comment: Yes I am referring to Subsonic with Firebird. It was typo mistake.

Comment: which subsonic do you mean? SS 3 or SS 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Projects Website:
...SubSonic is  A Super High-fidelity Batman Utility Belt...:-)

Here is an useful review what Subsonic is and what not:
http://www.mojoportal.com/subsonic-all-your-databases-are-belong-to-us.aspx

Comment: I read that article. Mojo Portal seems to be using Firebird provider for Subsonic but no links have been given for that provider. If i am not wrong Mojo has changed Subsonic as its provider.